# Background-color column fill until bottom of the page, even the page grows

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the column color grows until the bottom of the page without specify the height, but i'm troubled in the css,
this is what I want to make:

```
  +-------------------------------------------------+
  |            |        Header                      |
  |            +------------------------------------+
  |            |                                    |
  |            |                                    |
  |Navigation  |         Content                    |
  |            |                                    |
  |            |                                    |
  |            |                                    |
  |            |                                    |
  +------------|                                    |
  |   footer   |                                    |
  +------------+------------------------------------+
```

---

The left column height doesn't follow the right column height.

This is what I use:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row>
      <div class="col-md-3">
          <div>
             NAVIGATION GOES HERE
          </div>

          <div class="footer">
             FOOTER
          </div>               
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
          <div class="header">
               HEADER GOES HERE
          </div>
          <div>
             Site Content Goes here
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: first of all, you have no semantic frontend!

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: Can you post your full code thx :D

Comment: @amrjo Please accept the answer if it helped you to solve the issue !

Comment: can you add code in jsfiddle?

Comment: Just wanted to know what's the issue with codepen link ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with your markup kept same.

Basically you will need to set

`.row{
      display: -webkit-box !important;
      display: -ms-flexbox !important;
      display: -webkit-flex !important;
      display: flex !important;
      overflow: hidden;
    }`

The full working example can be found [here](http://codepen.io/kushalmahajan/pen/obYRNj)

Let me know if you have any questions !

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: I have already pasted the required code keeping in mind the same markup in the question. So I feel it answers practically. The linked pen is just an additional reference for the full code. Anyhow the pen is controlled by me and I doubt it will change.